# Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods'

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoa-pods got this error in terminal.  I have searched a lot and tried many solution which were available on stackoverflow but nothing work for me. Please help how can i get out of this problem..

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
  ED: Connection refused - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Are you behind proxy?